# How to update Python PygreSQL package on Linux Debian?

Tags: python, linux, debian, pygresql

I have Linux Debian installed.
In debian repository the newest **stable** version of PygreSQL is 4.0

The newest version of PygreSQL  is 5.0.2 but I don't see debian in thier site:
http://www.pygresql.org/download/index.html

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the source code of the package
2. Install it locally within your python installation
   with virtualenv:
   pip install --no-index --find-links file:your path here name of module

system wide:
    sudo pip install --no-index --find-links file:your path here name of module

Maybe you have to add dependent modules too.

Hope that helps.

JJ

Comment: Which sourcecode? Thier site does not have a package for debian

Comment: Is there a reason why debian repository is outdated?

Comment: Debian is all about stability so they usually don't update unless there's a huge security risk involved. I'm not sure if this is the reason why pygresql isn't up-to-date though. It may also be that psycopg2 is a bit more popular so pygresql simply gets less attention.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to uninstall the version of pygresql you have right now. Then follow one of the methods below.

To install Pygresql system wide, you'll need to follow the [Compiling Manually](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/install.html#compiling-manually) steps. You can also make a package by following [How to Package For Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian). This is probably the best way which gives your dev ops and/or sys admins the most control.

Another way would be to install development packages like `python-dev, libpython-dev, libpq-dev` (I may be missing some, but hopefully you get the big picture), then running a `pip install pygresql`. I'd try this out in a virtualenv before installing it system wide.